# How to get rid of light/dark bands at high refresh rate

Tags: windows, display

I'm using an HP Zbook, which is supposed to have "LED-backlit FHD WVA anti-glare" display. I noticed that on the standard refresh setting (60Hz), I can see ~0.5cm wide light/dark bands flowing up the screen. It looks like a very subtle version of what happens when trying to take a video of TV with a mobile phone.

The bands disappear completely when I switch to 40Hz, but I'd like to know if there's any chance they're caused by software issues? Is there anything in Windows I can try to tweak besides the refresh rate to get rid of it?

Edit: comment answers:

- OS: win 8.1
- zbook: 17'' (display as described above), nvidia quadro K2100M
- software: anything - the effect is there all the time, but most visible with solid background - like most websites

Comment: Could be caused by a V-sync issue, if any of that was adjustable, the standard windows desktop render is supposed to maintain v-sync as on for itself.  What is the OS specific that is being used? What is the zbook specific that is being used?  what is the software your observing this issue in most?

Comment: Added answers. I don't think you can switch vsync on windows itself explicitly. At least nvidia control panel doesn't seem to expose that.